# What is the purpose of flag kern.geom.debugflags in FreeBSD?

Tags: linux, filesystems, freebsd

My question is as stated above, on a FreeBSD system, what is the use of the `kern.geom.debugflags`?

I see it written before the command to write on to a disk.

```
sysctl kern.geom.debugflags=16
```

What does it do and is there any Linux equivalent of the following command?

Answer (score 6):

Out from the box you cannot write to MBR of disk, which is the one FreeBSD boots from. After setting `sysctl kern.geom.debugflags=16` (or `kern.geom.debugflags=0x10`, which is all the same) you get allowed to shoot in the foot and write to MBR.

It's useful to backup and restore MBR or bootcode using `dd`:
[image: backup and restore MBR via dd]

The only way to write into MBR without touching this sysctl is to boot your FreeBSD in single-user mode and work with MBR while root filesystem is mounted read-only. If boot in single-user mode and then remount root filesystem in rw-mode, you will need to set this sysctl to write into MBR. If normally boot in multi-user mode and then go to single-user mode (by typing `shutdown now` without `-r` or `-h` arguments), you would still need to deal with this sysctl to write into MBR.

Comment: This example is only related to systems with MBR partition table, not with GPT.

Comment: Got `badblocks: Operation not permitted while trying to open /dev/ada1` running `badblocks -ws -b 4096 /dev/ada1` (on FreeNAS), this solved and explained it.